# PL SQL oracle instr function|anomalous behaviour

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am getting a rather strange behaviour when invoking oracle instr function, or probably I'm blind enough not to see my stupid mistake.

Actually I written a procedure to split a string. For example if we  have string

a,e,i,o,u

then my split method will look like

```
         string_split('a,e,i,o,u',',',5);
```

where first parameter is the string to split while second one is the separator and third one is the number of element I know is there after splitting.

Now, of number of things , one thing my procedure do is invoke

```
  start_index := instr(temp_string_to_split,',',1,(total_element-i));
```

But the moment it is invoked I get a

```
   ORA-06512 ,numeric or value error
```

But if I invoke

```
start_index := instr(temp_string_to_split,1,(total_element-i));
```

the procedure runs,though not in a desirable manner. Note that in second invocation separator parameter is missing, and directly number is passed as the second parameter, which I guess should have cause big time exception. But surprisingly it goes and run fine.

Can somebody explain this anomaly...or help me see if I'm missing something.

Thanks,
Mawia

Comment: Can you post the hole mehtod `string_split`. I don't know how you determine `total_element`!

Comment: As to why you get the exception: I also suspect `total_elements` - try to remove it and see if you get the exception. As for why the second works (with no "big time exception"): the 3rd and 4th arguments in `instr` are optional so it probably cast implicitly the `1` to a string `'1'` (if you'll have `1` in your `temp_string_to_split` you'll probably get the index of the first occurence)

Comment: ORA-06512: "**Cause:** Backtrace message as the stack is unwound by unhandled exceptions." [1] In addition to providing a test case with your problem, or the code to split string, please provide the full stack trace from the error. Note 1: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e17766/e4100.htm#sthref2109

Comment: The 3-parameter call to `INSTR` with a numeric second parameter does not generate an error because the parameter is being converted to a string. For example. `SELECT INSTR( '12345', 23 ) FROM DUAL` returns `2` instead of generating an error.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that in your call to `instr`, `temp_string_to_split` is the string that was passed to `string_split`, and `(total_element-i)` is meant to be an iterator over the number of splits to make.  (As an aside, it seems odd that you have `','` hardcoded in this call, when you appear to be passing it as a parameter to `string_split`.

I tried emulating this with the following SQL, which worked fine:

```
SELECT LEVEL,instr('a,e,i,o,u',',',1,LEVEL)
from dual connect by level < 5;
```

Do you know the exact values of `temp_string_to_split`, `total_element`, and `i` on the call to `instr` that caused the error?

Comment: The variant, `SELECT LEVEL,instr('a,e,i,o,u',',',1,LEVEL-1) from dual connect by level <= 5;` produced `ORA-01428: argument '0' is out of range`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot all for responding.

Actually as I told earlier, I was calling

```
 start_index := instr(temp_string_to_split,',',1,(total_element-i));
```

in a loop. Now as a final value of the loop

```
 (total_element-i)
```

was getting negative. And this was the root of malady.

One thing, I'm still puzzled though is as it was a run time generated condition, that is to say everything before the final invocation was legal. Then why I dont see on console the result of few of DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE statement which I had put into to trace the execution.

Thanks,
Mawia